# Dynamic grid photo gallery for Wordpress is not showing images properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having issues with one of my wordpress page. i am trying to show image gallery but the full images are not showing, i am not understanding what is the issue.

please guide me

http://www.photographercourses.org/portrait-photography/

thank you.

Comment: what pictures? I see nothing

Comment: there is no height on your div that contains the images `id="dynamic-grid-gallery-3468"`.. not sure what plugin you are using, but you should be able to apply a height attribute.. EDIT: or you may need to add it to this one `id="dg-gallery-wrap"`.. could just add a new style to your stylesheet to assign a height to said div..

Comment: I can't use any height, because if I use any height, I will be fixed

Comment: I am using this wordpress plugin : http://codecanyon.net/item/dynamic-grid-photo-gallery-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css genesis18.css:545 you have this :

```
.entry-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you remove this it will work, but you'll probably broke something else, it depends on your theme and page contents!

Comment: mate i had already tried this, but the content of the page is not showing .. pictures are overlapping over this content

Comment: You need to remove absolute positionning (css class dg-column-wrap), replace it by left floating with an ending div clear: both;

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what pictures you are referring to, but there are a couple errors on the page you provided. It seems the path you provided is incorrect. Make sure to check path and ***ALWAYS*** check your console...

[image]